# Battery management system

Tags: bms

I am designing a battery management system for lithium ion batteries. I am referring a schematic that is already available.

I do not understand the function of the two MOSFETs marked in the schematic.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the datasheet of the chip that is driving those MOSFET gates? If so, was there commentary in the datasheet that you need help interpreting?

Comment: I can understand one is for charging and the other for discharging. How do they work here?

Comment: They either conduct or they don't. You need two back-to-back because of the body diodes (on mobile so no time to write full answer)

Comment: A BMS does not charge a battery. It is not a battery charger. As explained, the 2 Fets are here to disconnect the battery to protect it (under-discharge, over-charge, over-temperature, overcurrent etc).
2 Fets are needed because Mosfets have a parasitic body diode that will let the current flow from Source to Drain. A second Mosfet in the opposite direction is necessary to interrupt the current in both directions.

Comment: The CFOUT and DFOUT pin descriptions in the datasheet should have all the info you need.

Comment: What is the purpose of a MOSFET switch when the fuse has blown off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They together work as a bidirectional relay.

It's a well known circuit in literature.

The states of this solid state relay are: ON or OFF.

When the relay is in the ON state, current can flow in both the directions.

Comment: What is the purpose of a MOSFET switch when the fuse has blown off?

Comment: I can't answer. I would have measured the output and input currents and would have turned off the MOSFET's under overcurrent conditions instead of using a slow fuse.